# c# handles range-specific requests

Tags: c#, download, range

im looking for method that help me to get client GET request for serving file in advance

i have code in server 1 and file on server2,

server1 download file on server2 after receive download command from my client, 
file start download but only one segment,

ok there is no good way to server download with multi segment so i figure out

if i send file size and let my client download manager split file for start download with multi segment and my server1 recive download range it would be good way,

but i cant find any resource to help me out

so i need to get download range from my client

===========================

i find this method : httplistener to GetContext